# Redirecting the output of ffmpeg in subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, python-3.6

I have a folder named `video_files` where I have stored a bunch of video files e.g. `100.mp4, 101.mp4...`. I have written a python script that iterates over each video file. Using the `subprocess` to call `ffmpeg` to extract the frames and then save the frames to the output directory named as `frames`. Here is my sample code for the same:

```
def frame_extractor(video_files_path):
        video_files = sorted(glob.glob(video_files_path + "**/*.mp4", recursive=True))
        print("Number of video files found: ", len(video_files))
        for i, video in enumerate(video_files):
            subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-i", video, "%04d.png"]
        print("Extracted frames from all the videos")
```

The problem is that it extracts the frames in the present directory, from where I run this script but I want the frames to be extracted in the `frames` folder.

P.S: `frames/%04d.png` doesn't work.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a call after your function finishes to move all of the output files.

```
import os
import glob

for img in glob.glob(video_files_path + '**/*.png', recursive=True):
    img_out = os.path.join('frames', os.path.split(img)[-1])
    os.rename(img, img_out)
```

Comment: That I am doing as of now but I don't want that. Is there no way to modify the subprocess call in any way?